# Show parameter values inside table RDLC Report

Tags: c#, report, rdlc

I need to show parameters values inside table of rdlc report. When I put static text it is showing but parameter's values showed empty.

I need to show data in below format which can b easily done using table.[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can show report parameters using this syntax:

```
=Parameters!YourParameterName.Value
```